# Animate element when new element is loaded

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I don't think I can explain this very well in words, so here's a gif:

[image]

The `p` is a `<p>` tag that appears when it's display is changed to block in js (by default it's none).

When this happens, `h1` shifts a bit upward. (here it's only one line, it's usually more)

How can I go about animating h1's movement upward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can harness `display: table` and `display: table-cell` properties to emulate a gravity to the bottom using `vertical-align: bottom`.

Then with a little bit of jQuery goodness, you should be able to trigger CSS animations on specific events, such as the loading of a new element.

Check out this [implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/mrcendre/59b0xnug/) on JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet, hObj is the h1 tag you wish to move and pObj is the paragraph tag you want to insert later. You can use css transitions to animate objects.

```js
var hObj = document.getElementById("hObj");
var pObj = document.getElementById("pObj");

function move(){
  hObj.style.top = "60px";
  hObj.addEventListener("transitionend", function(){ pObj.style.visibility = "visible"; });
}
```

```html
<h1 style="position:absolute; left:100px; top:100px; transition:top 0.5s linear; cursor:pointer; " id="hObj" onclick="move()">h1</h1>
<p style="position:absolute; left:100px; top:100px; visibility:hidden" id="pObj">p</p>
```